# Allow user to share their achievement from my web game via Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to allow a user to post their score/achievement from my web based HTML5 game via Facebook. I want to:

- Customize what text is written as part of the post
- Share a snapshot of their achievement badge (specify a URL for the image)

All the documentation I've read appears deprecated:

- [User scores](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/user/scores)
- [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) - `picture`, which is a field I need, is deprecated
- [Scores and Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements) - slated for deprecation

[Game Services Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/sharing) seems promising but it provides no example code on how to make it work.

If I try using the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) with test meta tags (they say I need to set meta tags to customize the post):

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

I was expecting it would show the image of The New York Times but it doesn't seem to honor the tags

```
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://spywatchlex.com',
    }, function(response){});
```

The [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) also seems to support `quote` as a param, but the quote text I've specified doesn't show up in my test post.

I simply want to allow a user to click the button and share their earned badge w/ text I specify as part of the post.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: looks fine for me in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2015%2F02%2F19%2Farts%2Finternational%2Fwhen-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html

Comment: _“I was expecting it would show the image of The New York Times but it doesn't seem to honor the tags”_ - it is honoring the `og:url` tag, by which you are telling it, hey, this content doesn’t really reside here, please go look under _this_ URL for the actual meta data to use when this gets shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `quote` parameter of the Share Dialog for custom text: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params

You have to provide the picture as `og:image` tag, as you found out already. Make sure to set `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` too.

Comment: Okay but If I'm hard coding the image to share in the meta tags, how can I share a dynamic image based on the badge the player earned? The game is a single page app and the New York Times meta tags per article (which has its own page) wont work in this case

Comment: you cannot share a dynamic image, unless it is part of a unique url. (yourdomain.com/?id=xxx) hash routes don't work, btw. (yourdomain.com/#xxx)